# Securing an Apache Setup with a Fresh Ubuntu Web Server with users and permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, security, permissions, ubuntu-10.04, web-server

I have a virtual Server with Ubunto 10.04 on. My host Mediatemple have a few guides on trying to [secure the apache config](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(ve):Secure_Apache_configuration), but I think they are missing some details, or at least it makes no sense to me. I have followed the guide on [creating a web user and group](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(ve):Add_user_and_group) but I can't seem to get the groups to be setup right and I don;t trust that they are secure.

I have read the question and answers on [Securing a fresh Ubuntu server](https://serverfault.com/questions/42/securing-a-fresh-ubuntu-server) and have made some of the steps to securing my server. This includes setting up a new admin user and disabling root logon. I also would like to be able to sftp into my server (I user Transmit) and upload files to the websites directories but when I logon as my newly created web or new admin user it says I don't have permission to create or save files. I assume with the admin account I need sudo permissions (which I have setup already)

Currently my web directory structure is:

```
/var/www/website.com/{html,django,logs}
/var/www/website.net/{html,django,logs}
```

What users/groups/permissions do I need to setup and apply to the folders. Can I have it so new websites added to the www folder are running under the correct user automatically. I will be running django from the django folders so I assume I need the execute ability?

I also need to have it possible to upload files to the web folders. How can I setup a good way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this question on [hardening Apache](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/77/485) over on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

As well as links to various hardening guides ([NSA](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/webs/archived/apacheWS.pdf), [CIS](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.show.single.apache.300), [DISA](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/downloads/zip/unclassified_web_srr_checklist_apache_v6r1-12_20100423.zip) and [Pete Freitag](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm)), the question looks at the following:

- Use SSH key based logins
- Secure MySQL
- Disable phpMyAdmin, webmin, etc
- Close all ports/processes that are not needed
- Use a file integrity checker
- Use mod_security Set the proper permissions/groups